# Core data executeFetchRequest returns NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data

In Core data, I have three types of entities.
Entity A, Entity B, Entity C

Entity C to entity A is a one to many relationship.
Entity C to entity B is also a one to many relationship.

In another word, Both A and B has an `inRecord` field which points to a single instance of Entity C.

I have the following code

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityA"];

    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inRecord.title = %@", title];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *arrayOfEntity = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Now if I check the class of arrayOfEntity[0], it will say it is of class EntityA.
However, with the exact same code, if I replaced EntityA by EntityB above, if I check the class of arrayOfEntity[0], it does not say EntityA, instead, it says it is class NSManagedObject.

Why is that?

Comment: Have you checked in the Core Data Model inspector if the "Class" of "EntityB" is set to "EntityB"?

Comment: Did you set the entity class in the entity properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the "Class" of the entity in the Core Data Model inspector
to your managed object subclass.

(The class is set automatically if you *create* a custom class for the entity with
"Editor -> Create Managed Object Subclass ..." from the Xcode menu.)